# wp_nav_menu só funciona na header.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Tenho 2 menus no site Wordpress que estou desenvolvendo (topo e rodape). O problema é que a função wp_nav_menu só está funcionando corretamente quando colocado no header.php. Estou registrando os menus da seguinte forma:

```
function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(    
            'header' => __( 'Menu Header' ),
            'footer' => __( 'Menu Footer' ),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

e estou exibindo no header assim:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header','items_wrap'      => '<ul class="menu-dinamico">%3$s</ul>' ) );
```

e no footer assim:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer' ) );
```

Sim, já associei os menus no painel do wordpress. O do header funciona normal, o do footer imprime uma div com uma classe que nem estou entendendo de onde vem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu recorto o código do menu do footer.php e colo no header.php ele funciona! Alguém saberia me dizer porque isso está acontecendo e como resolver?

Answer (score 0):

ok...descobri o problema, vou responder caso alguém um dia passe por isso. O site que estou desenvolvendo busca os posts numa rede multisite do worpress, e pra isso uso o switch_to_blog($id_destino) para ir em casa site buscar por postagens. O problema estava acontecendo pq eu havia esquecido de voltar para o site original usando switch_to_blog($id_site_original)...ou seja, ele estava procurando o menu em qualquer outro site da rede multisites.